# Toggle action when row is swiped to the left

Tags: ios, react-native, swipe, expo, gesture

i'm using `Swipeable` from `react-native-gesture-handler` for my iOS app build on Expo framework to swipe rows horizontally and display option (e.g. delete row).

On swipe to the left I display option on the right side (this works). When swiping even more I'd like to activate last button similar to when archiving email in iOS Email app, which I don't know how to do and seems Swipeable does not support such options.

Did anyone have similar struggle? How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a state variable counter and update it to 1 and 2 for left swipe and manage the two button visibility.

```
state={swipeCounter:0}
onleftSwipe()=>{
 const {swipeCounter}=this.state;
  this.setState({swipeCounter:swipeCounter+1});
}

<View style={{display:'flex';direction:'column'}}>
{swipeCounter===2?<Button>b2<Button>:null}
{swipeCounter===1?<Button>b1<Button>:null}
</View>
```